# Handling Removal of Elements with Data Join in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of circles on a graph with the following data and using the date, as each circles key:

```
data = [
 {date: '2012-01-01', amount: 100 },
 {date: '2012-01-02', amount: 200 },
 {date: '2012-01-03', amount: 300 },
 {date: '2012-01-04', amount: 400 },
 {date: '2012-01-05', amount: 500 }
]

var circles = container.selectAll("g.circles")
    .data(data, function(d){ return d.date; });

// ENTER
circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class","live")
  .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(y(d,i)); })
  .attr("cx", function(d){return xScale(x(d,i)); })
.transition(500)
  .delay(function(d,i){return i*50;})
  .style("display",function(d){ return y(d,i) === null ? 'none' : 'inline'; })
  .attr("r", radius - 3 )
  .attr("fill", "#f7f7f7")
  .attr('clip-path','url(#rpm-clip2)')
  .each("end", events);

// TRANSITION
d3.transition(circles)
  .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(y(d,i)); })
  .attr("cx", function(d){return xScale(x(d,i)); });
```

I then reload data with the following data set:

```
data = [
 {date: '2012-01-01', amount: 200 },
 {date: '2012-01-02', amount: 300 },
 {date: '2012-01-03', amount: 400 },
]
```

As you'll notice, this data set is shorter. I would like the dates that are missing to be removed but they aren't touched in the update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly remove them. The `.exit()` collection contains all nodes that don't have data:

```
circles.exit().remove();
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-exit